# Java Custom TreeModel: Using treeStructureChanged()

Tags: java, jtree, treemodel

I've built a custom TreeModel for my Java application and, as part of that, have set up my model to fire [TreeModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeModelListener.html) events.  The docs say to call treeStructureChanged() when the tree has drastically changed structure from a node down but I'm unclear what this means for actually using it.  When should my TreeModel call treeStructureChanged()?

Comment: You also might want to check [this answer](http://goo.gl/dZDT5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [this link](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/jtree/) (site changed and link is wrong now)

> In order to notify a listener of multiple inserts and deletes, or to
>   identify changes at multiple levels in the tree, you use
>   treeStructureChanged() and use the simple, no-children TreeModelEvent.
>   In this case, the path argument specifies a node in the tree that did
>   not change, and which has all of the other changes below it.

Answer (score 1):

When you implement the TreeModelListener, the callbacks (including treeStructureChanged) help in detecting when the tree changes.  treeStructureChanged callback is invoked in case of multiple inserts/deletes or if there are changes at multiple levels in the tree.  hope it helps